# Insert a python dictionary into postgres jsonb field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm looking to a `postgresql` query or function to replace the flowing `python` code

```
    def insert_data(pk, data)
        json_str = Employee.objects.filter(pk=pk).values_list('time_log', flat=True)[0]

        dt = data["date"]
        data.pop("date")
        if json_str.get(f"{dt}") == None:
            json_str[f"{dt}"] = [data]
        else:
            json_str[f"{dt}"].append(data)

        # time_log is a `jsonb field`
        Employee.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(time_log=json_str)
```

The code works but not efficient and causes bottlenecks.

Data is dictionary containing a date and two `datetime` objects like this:

```
    data = {
                '2021-08-13': [
                    {
                        'clock_in': '2021-08-15T04:16:41.307Z', 
                        'clock_out': '2021-08-14T21:16:44.491-07:00'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

IF the key does not exist, make a new key value pair, the key is the date in data and value is a list containing the data dictionary.

IF the key exists, append data into key of date from data dictionary.

The final result inside database is this:

```
    {
        '2021-08-13': [
            {
                'clock_in': '2021-08-15T04:16:41.307Z', 
                'clock_out': '2021-08-14T21:16:44.491-07:00'
            }, 
            {
                'clock_in': '2021-08-15T04:16:41.307Z', 
                'clock_out': '2021-08-14T21:16:46.714-07:00'
            }
        ], 
        '2021-08-14': [
            {
                'clock_in': '2021-08-15T04:16:41.307Z', 
                'clock_out': '2021-08-14T21:17:13.080-07:00'
            }, 
            {
                'clock_in': '2021-08-15T04:16:41.307Z', 
                'clock_out': '2021-08-14T21:26:32.252-07:00'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Your database design is terrible.  The RIGHT way to do this is to have another table called something like `clock_entries` that contains the clock in/out data, indexed by date and employee number.  It's just dumb to have a field that keeps growing and growing and growing.  How would you ever search that data?

Comment: Uncle Tim I don't know what you're talking about. I can query this field with single date, or with gt, gte, lt lookups, from there it basic list ops. Plus the max size of each List is just ever gonna be two dictionaries. What I'm trying to avoid is to load everything into memory at once

Comment: "The code works but not efficient and causes bottlenecks."  Can you elaborate on this?  Where are the bottlenecks?  What are they?  The question doesn't contain an actual question at the moment.

Comment: The flow from frontend to backend and back to frontend considerably slow as we add more data and have to search through it. Want to avoid loading the data into memory in the first place, got a suggestion?